# How to separate isql ouput columns with two tabs

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a utility (a wrapper around isql) which executes sybase queries and gives output. I want to separate 2 columns with two tabs. The help for the utility reads:

```
<-s>       : resets the column separator character, which is blank by default
```

I tried `-s\\t` which separates all the columns using a tab.

However trying -s\t\t gives weird output like:

```
1\t\tS1\t\tmaindb\t\t1\t\t1\t\t1\t\t1\t\t50\t\t10\t\t0\t\tNULL\t\tNULL\t\tNULL\t\tNULL\t\t1\t\t
```

I have also tried `-s'        '(eight spaces), -s"\t\t", -s/\t/\t(I knew this wouldn't work, but still), -s\2t, -s\t+1`, but nothing seems to work.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the `isql` command allows for a *string* as an argument to its `-s` option and not just a single character (I can't test this), then you should be able to specify two tabs using

```
isql -s $'\t\t' ...
```

in the `bash` shell.  You may also insert two *literal* tabs by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, or by using

```
isql -s "$( printf '\t\t' )" ...
```

If the option does not allow for more than a single separator character (as hinted at in the manual, where it says "the column separator *character*" rather than "the column separator *string*"), then there is not much you can do other than possibly post-process the result of the query.

The following would double up all tabs coming over the standard input stream from `isql` (using `bash` to insert a tab with `$'\t'`; GNU `sed` understands `\t` without the `$`, and in other shells, use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or the `printf` hack mentioned above):

```
isql -s $'\t' ... | sed $'s/\t/&&/g'
```

Comment: Yes, it did not allow the separator string. Have to go with post-processing the query results like you said.